# What exactly is a conifold for mathematicians?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

For physicists a conifold is a generalization of a manifold that has a singular point. For example the resolved conifold is the space given by the solutions of 
$$xy-zt = 0$$
where $(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb{C}$.
As we move far away from that point towards infinity the geometry looks like $S^2 \times S^3$. At the same time there is a proceedure known as smoothing the conifold for which we replace the zero by some complex number $\mu$,
$$xy-zt = \mu$$
and this is known as the deformed conifold. This one also looks like $S^2 \times S^3$ towards infinity. The [details can be found in reference](http://www.ictp-saifr.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/arXiv-hep-th-0410178.pdf)

I would like to ask though what do mathematicians refer to those constructions as and give me some reference maybe.

Comment: Are you looking for something like an orbifold? As for the smoothing operation, there are a lot of such things in geometry, and I'm not sure what would be the most appropriate one. At the very least, the idea of perturbing an equation $f(x) = 0$ to $f(x) = \epsilon$ in order to smooth out singularities isn't uncommon.

Comment: Hi, I assume that you are not a physicist so you have not heard it before. If you look at the link I provided page 13-16 you will see what I mention in the description of my question.

Comment: I'm familiar with the term 'conifold'. I'm asking whether you're asking for a generalization of a manifold with singularities, or the idea of smooth singularities on such a space.

Comment: Hi, not sure. I would just like to know how you would explain it to a mathematician familiar with complex geometry but not conifolds (and whatever their name in pure maths is). I am doing a project on CYs and one of the examples is the conifold and its transitions. The target is pure mathematicians. Also, is there a math reference explaining the conifold and the transitions?

Comment: Like I said, there's a huge array of methods of resolving singularities. I'm somewhat familiar with the topological side of things, but an algebraic geometer is probably a better person to talk with.